# How to create a trigger that moves data to another table when a table is truncated

Tags: oracle

I created the trigger but it doesn't move data to the other table

It creates the trigger successfully. It also truncates the table but the data is not moved.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE TRUNCATE ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
IF (ora_sysevent='TRUNCATE' and ora_dict_obj_name='testtab') THEN
INSERT INTO testtab2
SELECT name, id FROM testtab;
END IF;
END test_trigger;
```

Comment: @alex poole That was the problem thank u so so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the other references your source table does not have a quoted identifier, so it will be stored in uppercase in the data dictionary etc. [Read more in the docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA)That means you need the comparison to be uppercase too:

```
and ora_dict_obj_name='TESTTAB'
```

Not related, but it is good practice for your insert statement to list the target column names:

```
INSERT INTO testtab2 (name, id)
SELECT name, id FROM testtab;
```